# Getting date value from Excel to Sendkeys() Method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to get Date Value from Excel cell to `Sendkeys()` method if I use object as a variable? An error occuring at `sendkeys` like `Charsequence[]`.

```
object x=sheet.getRow(8).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
wd.findElement(By.id("MyMember_DateOfBirth")).sendKeys(x);
```

Comment: I am using POI jar files

Answer (score 0):

The method takes a charSquence/String, I'll assume that you get the content from the Sheet as a String reading the index or cell value.

Here is the Javadoc link might help

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html

```
void sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

never worked a lot on apache poi, but going through the api I would suggest you to take the date value in cell through

```
Date d=sheet.getRow(8).getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
```

Later you can use `SimpleDateFormat` class to get your date in string format.

or else you can use `DataFormatter` class in [poi](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) and use `formatCellValue` method for your usage.

Hope it helps.